# Código del botón "atrás" en C# .Net Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, botón

Estoy iniciando un sistema en visual studio usando C# .Net, mi duda es:
Cuando estoy en el login de mi programa, tengo 2 botones: uno de inicio de sesión y otro para regresar a la página anterior en la que estaba.

Mi duda es cómo configuro el botón de regresar para que efectivamente regrese a la página anterior.

Con el de iniciar sesión no tengo problema ya que todos los datos los extraigo de la base.

Adjunto una foto del diseño para que se hagan una idea de lo que hablo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Añade el código por favor, así otros se pueden guiar mejor al tener un problema referente al suyo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilicé `Response.Redirect("Nombre del formulario al que quería ir");`